# Вставка, определение или уточнение?

Tags: пунктуация

В течение всего ХХ века, наряду с еврейскими профессиями сапожника, портного, парикмахера, жестянщика и торговца, была ещё одна весьма важная - профессия фотографа".

В течение всего ХХ века, наряду с распространенными еврейскими профессиями - сапожник, портной, парикмахер, жестянщик, торговец, - была ещё одна весьма важная: фотограф"

В течение всего ХХ века, наряду с распространенными еврейскими профессиями -- сапожник, портной, парикмахер, жестянщик, торговец, была ещё одна весьма важная -- фотограф_.

Какой из этих вариантов правильный и почему?

Comment: @doom, Если вам дан исчерпывающий ответ, отметьте его как верный (нажмите на галку рядом с выбранным ответом).

Answer (score 2):

Из всех приведенных вами примеров правильным является первый. Обратимся к правилам. 
В вашем первом примере идет перечисление, а после - обобщающее словосочетание - "профессия фотографа" По правилам, если обобщающее слово следует за однородными членами, то перед ним ставится тире. Как в вашем примере.
Следует иметь в виду, что обобщающее слово уточняется, конкретизируется однородными членами. ***Оно является тем же членом предложения, что и однородные члены.*** В вашем втором примере обобщающее слово и однородные члены предложения - не являются одним и тем же членом предложения. Что касается второго тире. Создается впечатление, что обобщающем словосочетанием у вас является не " профессия фотографа", а "была ещё одна весьма важная". Второй пример можно оформить так: ***В течение всего ХХ века, наряду с распространенными еврейскими профессиями сапожник, портной, парикмахер, жестянщик, торговец, была ещё одна весьма важная -  фотограф"***
С третьим предложением, думаю, все ясно.
Подробнее об этом, см.: ***Справочник по правописанию и стилистике. Розенталь Д.Э. Полный академический справочник.***